# Клиент-серверное приложение в Android

Tags: java, android, база-данных, phpmyadmin, клиент-сервер

У меня есть БД в phpmyadmin, а также сайт. Мне надо брать данные с этой БД (или сайта), анализировать, а потом показывать информацию в приложении. Т. е. должна быть работа в фоне и если какое-то значение из БД меняется (допустим в БД было значение 90%, а потом, через какое-то время, постепенно уменьшаясь, стало меньше 10%), то нужно присылать уведомление, а когда человек просто заходит в приложение, то должны выводиться данные (90%...10%..."какой-то небольшой текст").
Можете ли вы мне подсказать, как это лучше реализовать (статьи, видео и т.д), так как я в интернете ищу информацию, но мне кажется, не совсем ту, которая подошла бы к моему проекту.

Comment: Если знаете английский вот чудесный сайт с курсами на любой вкус https://codingwithmitch.com/courses/

Answer (score 1):

Есть БД, серверная часть, и несколько клиентов.
Расскажу в двух словах как это обычно делается на примере Java.

БД у вас MySql

Сервер часть - например Spring

Клиента у вас два: web, mobile-android

Вся логика приложения крутится на сервере, клиенты отвечают только за получение информации от пользователя и отображения информации полученной от сервера.

На стороне сервера Spring обеспечивает получение, обработку и запись информации в БД через Hibernate. А так же с помощью Spring выставляете REST сервис для взаимодействия клиентов с сервером.

А дальше все клиенты обращаются по нужным REST адресам, получают информацию и отображают ее, и передают полученную информацию от пользователя.

Для описанного вами случая - пишете Scheduler на клиенте, который по таймеру стучится в нужный URL и получает данные. А там уже делаете все что хотите с этими данными.

Надеюсь, мой ответ вам поможет определится с направлениями в которых вам дальше копать.